# seo based multi-lingual url and regional targeting

Tags: url, url-rewriting, seo, search-engine, multilingual

We have been develping a new multi-lingual web portal and we are trying lots of seo practices in it. And so we are also using pretty urls to make site more specific for search engines.

My question here is , if i have a url targeting to english users which one is better :

```
http://mywebsite.com/en-US/index
http://mywebsite.com/en/us/index
```

Also, will this affect google location based targeting for region specific users. What i mean to say is will :

```
http://mywebsite.com/en-US
http://mywebsite.com/en-UK
```

be country specific results or users can see similar results in search engines.

thanks

EDIT:

still waiting to know which one is better from seo perspective :

```
en-US or en/us
```

Comment: why the down vote , care to elaborate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Google to understand the multilingual version of your website you have to implement `hreflang`. Google will display the right version of your website according to the language set.

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en-ie" hreflang="en-ie" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en-ca" hreflang="en-ca" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en-au" hreflang="en-au" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en" hreflang="en" />
```

> For language/country selectors or auto-redirecting homepages, you
>   should add an annotation for the hreflang value "x-default" as well:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="x-default"
> />
```

For more information: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

To verify the `hreflang` implementation you can check Google Search Console - > International Targeting.

Comment: so it means google cannot differentiate without hreflang?

Answer (score 1):

> still waiting to know which one is better from seo perspective :
>
> en-US or en/us

None is better than the other from a SEO perspective. They both help to differentiate.

BUT, you should use hreflang anyway to make sure Google understands what you are trying to achieve. If you don't, you're taking a risk Google won't get it like you want it.